# MySQL Error en el query

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas: (hay mas pero son las necesarias para este query...)

CICLISTA( **dorsal**, nombre, edad, nombrequipo);

MAILLOT(**código**, tipo, color, premio);

LLEVA(**código,numetapa**, dorsal);

Tengo que obtener los datos de los ciclistas que han vestido todos los maillots.

el query y la logica que sigo es una subconsulta con el numero de maillots distinto y comparando el mismo con el numero de maillots que ha llevado cada dorsal pero algo me falla.

```
select nombre 
from ciclista 
inner join lleva on lleva.dorsal=ciclista.dorsal 
group by ciclista.dorsal 
having count (distinct lleva.dorsal) = (select count(codigo) from maillot);
```

Me de error de sintaxis pero no encuentro el fallo ¿una ayudita?

Comment: Cual es el error de sintaxis que te muestra? Todos los campos que estes seleccionando en el SELECT deben estar en el GROUP BY, en este caso debes agregar GROUP BY nombre.

Answer (score -1):

Aquí te dejo una forma de hacerlo

```
select c.name
from ciclista c
INNER JOIN (
    select distinct ll.dorsal as dorsal, 
        COUNT(distinct ll.codigo) as totalPersonalizado,
        (select COUNT(m.Id) FROM maillot m) as total
        from lleva ll
        group by ll.dorsal) t
on t.dorsal = c.Id
AND t.totalPersonalizado = t.total
```

Te dejo el entorno que use para probarlo http://tpcg.io/uEJi8D

Comment: Responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, edita esto y explícalo

Comment: No vi el error en su código y le propuse otra forma de hacerlo, si hay alguna duda sobre mi método es libre de preguntar y le responderé lo mejor que sepa. No es un código complicado de entender.

Comment: Creo que te hace falta leer [answer] la explicación va desde el inicio y no hasta que el OP. Te lo pregunté

Comment: Esta respuesta va a ser consultada por mucha gente y no deben andar adivinando o preguntando n veces que hiciste